# Runtime replace Overlay marker image in mapview

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

I am using one overlay image in mapview to show multiple locations, now my requirement is like, when user click on that marker image, we need to change that image and should replace it with new image for that overlay only, it means if there are 5 overlay then we want to change only clicked image by user, rest 4 image should be as it is.

I have put both overlays here,

Marker Image,

[image]

Marker should be after clicked,

[image]

I do not know how to handle this thing runtime, so please suggest me how this thing can be done.
Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: tell me after changing marker you want the next image , and your requirement will be like the unser name and other text is dynamic?

Comment: @ robinhood: yes it is dynamic.... and we also want onclick listner for white arrow image...